# OpenVPN Tunnel not working for subnets after some time

Tags: routing, openvpn

okay this sounds weird, I have one OpenVPN Server with 2 clients, 1 client works fine, the second one drops out after about 1 day.

The server is 10.7.2.1, the client 1 10.7.2.2 (not working) and client 2 10.7.2.3.

The internal networks for each of those are:

**server (10.7.2.1):**
10.0.96.0/24

**client 1 (10.7.2.2):**
10.21.0.0/24
192.168.0.0/24

**client 2 (10.7.2.3):**
10.22.0.0/24

So after the day it's impossible to ping from say 192.168.0.3 to 10.0.96.253:

```
ping 10.0.96.253
PING 10.0.96.253 (10.0.96.253) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- 10.0.96.253 ping statistics ---
8 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 7590ms
```

I am sure the packets are correctly routed:

```
10.0.96.0/24 via 10.7.2.1 dev tun1 
10.7.2.0/24 dev tun1  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.7.2.2 
10.22.0.0/24 via 10.7.2.1 dev tun1
```

and can also verify via tcpdump:

```
[Interface:eth0:]    10:41:37.446320 IP 192.168.0.3 > 10.0.96.253: ICMP echo request, id 20316, seq 4, length 64
[Interface:tun1:]    10:41:37.446332 IP 192.168.0.3 > 10.0.96.253: ICMP echo request, id 20316, seq 4, length 64
[Interface:eth0:]    10:41:38.446967 IP 192.168.0.3 > 10.0.96.253: ICMP echo request, id 20316, seq 5, length 64
[Interface:tun1:]    10:41:38.446983 IP 192.168.0.3 > 10.0.96.253: ICMP echo request, id 20316, seq 5, length 64
```

tun1 is the network interface on client 1.

```
32: tun1: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN qlen 100
    link/none 
    inet 10.7.2.2/24 brd 10.7.2.255 scope global tun1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

When doing a tcpdump on the server side, nothing shows up!

**BUT** it does work if I ping directly from the client:

```
ping 10.0.96.253
PING 10.0.96.253 (10.0.96.253) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.0.96.253: icmp_seq=1 ttl=63 time=31.8 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.96.253: icmp_seq=2 ttl=63 time=31.3 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.96.253: icmp_seq=3 ttl=63 time=32.9 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.96.253: icmp_seq=4 ttl=63 time=31.7 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.96.253: icmp_seq=5 ttl=63 time=32.2 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.96.253: icmp_seq=6 ttl=63 time=38.4 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.96.253: icmp_seq=7 ttl=63 time=32.8 ms
^C
--- 10.0.96.253 ping statistics ---
7 packets transmitted, 7 received, 0% packet loss, time 6008ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 31.331/33.060/38.428/2.264 ms
```

Also visible in tcpdump

```
[Interface:tun1:]    10:44:41.828197 IP 10.7.2.2 > 10.0.96.253: ICMP echo request, id 51791, seq 5, length 64
[Interface:tun1:]    10:44:41.860386 IP 10.0.96.253 > 10.7.2.2: ICMP echo reply, id 51791, seq 5, length 64
```

After a reconnect of openvpn via systemctl restart openvpn@samba it works again!

Again from 192.168.0.3 to 10.0.96.253:

```
ping 10.0.96.253
PING 10.0.96.253 (10.0.96.253) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.0.96.253: icmp_seq=1 ttl=62 time=33.9 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.96.253: icmp_seq=2 ttl=62 time=31.4 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.96.253: icmp_seq=3 ttl=62 time=32.0 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.96.253: icmp_seq=4 ttl=62 time=32.9 ms
^C
--- 10.0.96.253 ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 3275ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 31.496/32.589/33.915/0.947 ms
```

and the corresponding tcpdump:

```
[Interface:eth0:]    10:47:25.230275 IP 192.168.0.3 > 10.0.96.253: ICMP echo request, id 31580, seq 4, length 64
[Interface:tun1:]    10:47:25.230301 IP 192.168.0.3 > 10.0.96.253: ICMP echo request, id 31580, seq 4, length 64
[Interface:tun1:]    10:47:25.262723 IP 10.0.96.253 > 192.168.0.3: ICMP echo reply, id 31580, seq 4, length 64
[Interface:eth0:]    10:47:25.262739 IP 10.0.96.253 > 192.168.0.3: ICMP echo reply, id 31580, seq 4, length 64
```

The second client doesn't show this behaviour.
So I'm quite stumped and don't know where to look, anyone any idea what I could do?

Server Config:

```
port                  1194
proto                 udp
dev                   tun
ca                    samba.ca.crt
cert                  samba.crt
key                   samba.key
dh                    samba.dh.pem
server                10.7.2.0 255.255.255.0
ifconfig-pool-persist samba.ipp.txt
route                 10.0.96.0 255.255.255.0
route                 192.168.0.0 255.255.255.0 10.7.2.2
route                 10.21.0.0 255.255.255.0 10.7.2.2
route                 10.22.0.0 255.255.255.0 10.7.2.3
topology              subnet
mode                  server

client-to-client

client-config-dir     samba.ccd
ccd-exclusive         samba.ccd
comp-lzo
persist-key
persist-tun
status                samba.openvpn-status.log
log-append            /var/log/samba.openvpn.log
verb                  4
keepalive             10 120
```

Server OpenVPN Version:

```
OpenVPN 2.3.8 x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [EPOLL] [PKCS11] [MH] [IPv6] built on Aug  4 2015
```

Client Config:

```
client
dev              tun
proto            udp
remote           xx.xx.xx.xx 1194
resolv-retry     infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
ca               samba.ca.crt
cert             samba.crt
key              samba.key
comp-lzo
verb             4
status           samba.openvpn-status.log
log-append       /var/log/samba.openvpn.log
```

Client CCD:

```
client-to-client
iroute 10.21.0.0 255.255.255.0
iroute 192.168.0.0 255.255.255.0
push "route 10.0.96.0 255.255.255.0"
push "route 10.22.0.0 255.255.255.0"
```

Client OpenVPN Version:

```
OpenVPN 2.3.8 x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [EPOLL] [PKCS11] [MH] [IPv6] built on Aug  4 2015
```

Comment: What does the routing table on the server look like when you are having the error? When you `tcpdump` on the server while the client's network (192.168.0.3) is pinging, do you see the packets go out on the wire to 10.0.96.253? Do you see them come back (viz. are you sure openvpn is the problem)?

Comment: Okay, need to wait for the problem to reoccur. Will tcpdump the outgoing udp packets and print all routing tables.

They definitely go in the TUN interface but don't come out the other side. So the ICMP Request isn't seen by the OpenVPN Server (e.g. 10.0.96.254)